# Automate gdebi in bash when it asks "y / n"

Tags: shell-script, ubuntu

I am trying to automate the installation of Adobe in a bash script.

1. The script downloads the package.deb
2. When I install it, it asks me Yes / no. That's what I want to automate and so far I had no success, the user always has to enter the option and that's what I don't want.

```bash
wget  --user xx@xxx --password xxx* ftp://www.xxx.com/drivers/adobe/AdbeRdr9.5.5-1_i386linux_enu.deb -S 
gdebi AdbeRdr9.5.5-1_i386linux_enu.deb <<< 'yes'
```

This doesn't work.

Answer (score 6):

You can make `gdebi` not ask at all with the `-n` option:

```
gdebi -n AdbeRdr9.5.5-1_i386linux_enu.deb
```

Comment: Hi! Try this option, but not the only thing it does is stop the script. any other idea?

Comment: Surely it does more than that! What does `gdebi` output when you use it as above? It should start with “Reading package lists... Done”.

Comment: this line continue: echo "application/pdf=acroread.desktop;firefox.desktop;" >> /usr/share/applications/defaults.list

Comment: I can't get it to stop asking and / or just confirming to make the installation automatic

Comment: any idea? for this